# Left crockpot unplugged for about an hour

Tags: food-safety, crockpot

I'm making chicken chili. Or trying to... This morning I turned on my crockpot to high for about 40 minutes. I then drove to work and replugged it, about an hour after unplugging it. After cooking it for 5 more hours, should it be safe?

Comment: Please see our food safety info under http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info, it describes when food left unheated is safe to eat and when it is not, and ends with links to our most important questions and answers on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It likely depends on if the food came up to 140°F (60°F) while you were still at home, and how much it cooled off during the trip.

Basically, your time in the 'danger zone' is cumulative, so it's the sum of:

1. Time to heat up to above 140°F (60°C)
2. Time from when it cooled down to below 140°F 'til it go back up to 140°F

So, if it never got up to 140°F, then it likely spent 2 hours in the 'danger zone'.  (40min + 1 hour + time to get up to 140°F), which some people consider to be right at the edge of acceptable.

... but if it got up to 140°F in the first 20 minutes, and it was well-insulated so didn't drop below 140°F until 30 min into the trip, and it came back up to temp 10 min after plugging it back in, you'd have had (20min + (1hr - 30min) + (10min) = 1hr ... which is well within recommended times.

These also assume that you didn't take a long time to get the chicken home from the store and/or leave it on the counter for 30 min while you were putting away other groceries.